# Azure Workflow -- I want to do something to only one file in a blob folder, when there may be many

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps, azure-workflow-automation

So, Azure Workflow editor does me the "courtesy" of creating a **For Each** iterator when I pull the list of files in a blob folder.  But!  What I want is a **For One** action.  Is there an add action that allows me to just process one of the files in the list that results from the prior action?

[image: I'd like this thing to be changed to a For One, instead of a For Each. I only want to process one.]

Answer (score 0):

> Azure Workflow -- I want to do something to only one file in a blob folder, when there may be many

Here, you have to use for each for sure and then use condition inside it as below design:

[image]

Current item is the blob which you want to work with. Here, i have used http trigger, you can use recurrence in place of it. Alternatively, Inside for each you can set the blob to a variable and then you can process that variable outside of it also.

**`Output:`**

If blob name matches:

[image]

If it does not match:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the quick response!

What if I don't know the name?  I just want it to process the first one it comes across.

Comment: You can firstly store all file names in an array variable and then use its first value.

Comment: Alright, that's something I can figure out how to go after.  So I can leap to the conclusion there's no "For 1 item do this task" action available.

As it stands now I can let the follow-on files just crash because they're not allowed to overwrite the destination file location.  But I'm hoping to not have the process show Error when it's working correctly.  I wonder if there is an Exit action that I can run at the end of the process, that will effectively end the loop.

Comment: AFAIK, there is no such action @JohnL.Edwards

Comment: No solution yet.  Sometimes this stuff really feels like coding inside a box with your eyes closed.  With old solutions you could just exit the code after the first one completed.  This draggy-droppy thing means you're much more limited, coding on a rail.

Comment: One way is initializing a variable with true before foreach and in condition keep like variable isequal to true, then in true action of condition change the variable value to false. So by this way only one iteration is possible, hope you get it. https://i.imgur.com/GL4jXOm.png

Comment: Or use Until like this https://i.imgur.com/caR2psU.png, here after first iteration the value will be set to false because of which until terminate

Comment: Alright, so I'm sorta almost in the neighborhood, but I need to make sure a particular file name doesn't exist as well, and that seems to just be beyond the pale in this stuff.  Every time I try to figure out if the list of blobs contains a certain file the interface does me the "favor" of turning it into a For Each and then not doing what I want it to.

Sure am glad I get paid by the hour.

Comment: God, this is just awful work.  The tool just . . . INSISTS that I have to loop through every single blob for every single action I take.  When I try to terminate the loop or the entire run it throws an error.  This really is like programming with both arms tied behind your back.  I don't know how you guys deal with this.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, so as of this moment, I'm confident that the answer to this question is No.  Rithwikbojja stated that above in the comments, and my work on this brings me to agreement.  **There are not "state of blob list" functions available like exists_in_list or length_of_list or list_is_empty.  All functions provided apply to a single item within the list.**

Oh, and terminate functions don't run within loops for some reason.  So you'll loop through everything, every time.

*That said, you can do plenty of loops through the list of blobs, one after the other, in order to gain the information you need to eventually perform a process on all of the objects that only has an effect on one.  **In my case all I needed to do was to find a file by name and, if it doesn't exist, rename one of the blob files to that name.***

So for me this was the following --

1. Get the list of blobs.
2. Loop through the list of blobs.
   2a. On each pass of the loop, determine if the name of the blob is the name I'm looking for, true or false.
   2b. On each pass of the loop, copy the name of the current blob into a variable.

   . . . The result of this loop is that at some point a "file found" variable gets set to true if the file exists.  The variable is initialized to false before the loop, gets set to true in one pass if the file name is found.
   The name of each file gets written into a "file name to process" variable.  It's set each pass through the loop, ending up with the last file name in the list as its final value.  Sigh . . . not sweet programming, but it gets all my bs set up for the real pass.  So far I've done no real work, just gotten stuff set up.
3. Loop through the list of blobs again.
   3a.  On each pass, IF the current blob has the "file name to process" AND "file found" is false, then copy that blob to the target file name, make a copy to an archive folder, and delete that blob from the folder.
   3b.  If the conditions in 3a are not met, do nothing.

. . . That is, loop through the entire set no matter what, doing nothing, except for that one place (last pass through the loop) where the file name matches, and only then when the target file name doesn't exist.

This reminds me of programming in assembly 40 years back.  Everything is atomic, everything is done in its most elementary form.  For the life of me I don't understand why Microsoft hasn't fleshed this out with additional functions.  It seems designed to force us hourly workers to bill more hours to our customers.  Sure am glad I'm paid by the hour for this work.  My old system made functions like this super-easy, perhaps half a dozen lines of code.